# sqlldr : Load Multiple columns of a csv file in a single column

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, sql-loader

I have a CSV file which can contain multiple columns.

Say example the records are as below.

```
3333,Y,ABC
2222,Y,PQR
1111,N,FFF
```

The table has 2 columns

```
Column 1 (Number), Column 2 (varchar2(4000)).
```

I want to load the 1st field from the CSV into Column 1 of table and rest all fields of the file into Column 2. How to achieve it?

Comment: Have you actually tried writing any code to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it.

```
CREATE TABLE myt
(
   col1   NUMBER,
   col2   VARCHAR2 (200)
);
```

Control file:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
INSERT
INTO TABLE MYT
(
    COL1 terminated by ',',
    COL2 terminated by '\n' "REPLACE(:COL2,',')"
)
BEGINDATA
3333,Y,ABC
2222,Y,PQR
1111,N,FFF
```

Your first column is terminated by a comma. And rest of the line is considered as single column terminated by new line character. If you want to get rid of
commas from second column, use the replace function.

```
SQL> select * from myt;

      COL1 COL2
---------- --------
      3333 YABC
      2222 YPQR
      1111 NFFF
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of argument, here's another way to do it.  Using "Eat A Peach"'s setup, this method defines the input fields as BOUNDFILLER, which means treat them as FILLER, but remember them for use as BIND data later.  Then make COL2 equal to the concatenation of input fields 1 and 2:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
INSERT
INTO TABLE MYT
fields terminated by ','
trailing nullcols
(
 COL1
,INPUTCOL2 BOUNDFILLER
,INPUTCOL3 BOUNDFILLER
,COL2 ":INPUTCOL2||:INPUTCOL3"
)
BEGINDATA
3333,Y,ABC
2222,Y,PQR
1111,N,FFF
```